# @track property is not rending in html on second time(when i go from screen 1 to 2 )

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, web

fNameVal----> is rendering in html in fine manner, but when i go back again in to screen1 and edit the text box the value is stucking

.js

```
   screenOnedHandler(event)
         {
          event.preventDefault();

             const fieldApiName=event.target.name;
             let value=event.target.value;
 
            
           
                   // Adding all the fields except add ress and phisicall address
                   this.leadStepOneDatarest[fieldApiName]=value;
                   console.log('fieldApiName'+fieldApiName);
                   console.log('fieldApiName value'+value);
                   console.log('leadStepOneData for storing the rest data ---->'+JSON.stringify(this.leadStepOneDatarest));
 
                   if(fieldApiName==='FirstName'){
                    this.fNameVal='';
                    console.log('FirstName value Before---->'+JSON.stringify(this.fNameVal));
                   
                    this.fNameVal=value;
                    console.log('FirstName value- AFter--->'+JSON.stringify(this.fNameVal));
                   }

                  
 
         }
```

.html

```
 <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                                    <lightning-input data-my-id="screen1"  class="firstNameCmp" label="First Name"  name="FirstName" onchange={screenOnedHandler} required></lightning-input>
                                </lightning-layout-item>
    
                  <div class="slds-m-left_none">
                            <lightning-layout horizontal-align="center">
                               <lightning-layout-item>
                                   <h2 style="font-size: large;">Hello {fNameVal}! What’s your contact and company information?</h2>
                               </lightning-layout-item>                    
                            </lightning-layout>
                            
                            <lightning-layout horizontal-align="center">
                                <lightning-layout-item>
                                   <h6 style="font-size: 90%;">Just in case we need to contact you about setting up your account.</h6>
                                </lightning-layout-item>
                            </lightning-layout>
                          <br/>
                          <br/>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the html code as well? Also are you having components embedded inside one another?

Comment: Could you elaborate what your problem is? What value is being "stuck"?